# What comes next in this number sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

What comes next in this sequence?
1, 4, 3, 11, 15, 13, ?

> No complex Maths is required!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

> 17, according to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001166).

Reasoning:

> *1 (one)* requires three letters to write in English, and is the smallest number to do so.
>  *4 (four)* requires four letters to write in English, and is the smallest number to do so.
>  *3 (three)* requires five letters to write in English, and is the smallest number to do so.
>  *11 (eleven)* requires six letters to write in English, and is the smallest number to do so.
>  *15 (fifteen)* requires seven letters to write in English, and is the smallest number to do so.
>  *13 (thirteen)* requires eight letters to write in English, and is the smallest number to do so.
>  ***17 (seventeen)*** requires **nine** letters to write in English, and is the smallest number to do so.